# How to create Rating Dots

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressbar

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

There should be always 5 dots in total, but the black colored Dots can be variable.
Is there any Github Project or something like that? 
I tried it with Subclasses of the UIProgressbar but that not reallys worked well!

```
cell.ratingDot.numberOfPages = 5;
cell.ratingDot.alignment = GTControlAlignmentLeft;
cell.ratingDot.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//Its not possible as you can see to set more than one dot to the  ratingDot value
cell.ratingDot.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: @David: What do you really want...? the logic? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick search on GitHub with *rating ios* as query](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=rating%20ios&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) gives me this :

- [EDStarRating](https://github.com/erndev/EDStarRating)
- [HCSStarRatingView](https://github.com/hugocampossousa/HCSStarRatingView)

> Tips: when browsing GitHub, type one or two words max. describing what you need, followed by the official StackOverflow tag (eg. ios,java, etc).

Comment: HCSStarRatingView is what i´m looking for, can´t believe i did not found this after 1h of searching... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about…

A `UIView`, with 5 `UIImageView` subviews, each imageView has a regular and highlighted image:

```
- initWithImage:highlightedImage:
```

then set the `highlighted` property of each imageView depending on the rating.

Rather than just pulling in some 3rd party code, use it as an opportunity to learn!